# I need to see a doc and to relocate for a job, what do I do?

Tags: startup, health, start-date

This is unrelated to my previous question.

I think I may need to see a doc for a relatively minor thing (specially since it might affect my work), and I'm also negotiating an offer that requires me to relocate. Traveling to or from the destination city is expensive, and there's a huge chance that a doctor appointment date would be later than the starting date.

I honestly have no idea how to handle it. Is it too far fetched to ask to delay the start date a little? Specially since we haven't agreed on that yet, but I suspect they want me to start soon.

What would you do?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere It's the same one, but this thing is an unrelated medical issue. I haven't discussed the need for medical time off because after all I don't even know anything yet, just that in the case of a friend years ago he needed weekly visits.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere In the end I won't need to, the issue I was talking about was minor in the first place and got better by itself in a couple days :) I apologize for the off-topic but I've seen you comment in this community and I'd like your opinion in this other thing. I've got an "offer letter" that says a different starting date than the guy told me over the pone, and it's a starting date that could be a problem with relocation. I'd ofc adapt if needed, but the guy said I didn't need to start that early so I said that then I wouldn't sign a document that says otherwise.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I haven't gotten a modified version of that offer letter yet, and honestly think that the guy just didn't understand me. It's silly but I'm scared of insisting. But I don't know what to say or if it's a red flag that 2 weeks before starting I haven't been asked to sign a contract.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere You responded while I was writing the continuation :P I asked them to modify it and they haven't yet, they keep saying to not worry about that. I don't even know if he understood me.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Sure, there's no way I'm signing it. Just wanted to see if you thought it was fishy or if there was something I should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it too far fetched to ask to delay the start date a little?

Not at all. Negotiating a start date (for a variety of reasons) is extremely common.

Once you are at the offer point, discuss your desire to delay the start a little.

If "little" in this context just means a week or two, you will likely have no problems. If it means months or years, then there might be issues.

You won't know if you don't ask.

Comment: I thought I had responded to you, no idea what happened. I apologize if there's a double comment later. To the point: I was referring to a week or two at most and that's already saying a lot. I'm worried because it's a tech startup though. By the way to whoever downvoted this question I think it's really rude to try to silence someone who's in a tough spot and seeking advice.